# Catch exit 1 in a function

Tags: bash, shell, sh

here is my shell script, I tried to catch the failing command and print the its result:

```
myfunc() {
  $1
  uptime

  echo "-------------------------------------"
  
  EXIT_STATUS=$?
  if [ ! "$EXIT_STATUS" = "0" ]; then
    echo "Exit on failure"
  else
    echo "Exit on success"
  fi
}

myfunc pwd
myfunc failfail
```

which results in:

```
/root
 15:19:54 up 15:43,  3 users,  load average: 0.01, 0.09, 0.09
-------------------------------------
Exit on success
test2.sh: line 4: failfail: command not found
 15:19:54 up 15:43,  3 users,  load average: 0.01, 0.09, 0.09
-------------------------------------
Exit on success
```

which second time should print `Exit on failure`, I tried with `set -e` but actually it exit the code and not continue to `if else` statement.

Comment: ...if your _real_ goal is to find any unchecked command with status 0, that's what an ERR trap is for.

Comment: BTW, note that you should probably be running `local exit_status; "$@"; exit_status=$?` at the top of `myfunc`. The `echo` needs to be _after_ you collected `$?`, and if you don't declare `exit_status` local, the assignment is going to change it globally for your script.

Comment: (Use of lower-case variables above is also intentional; see the relevant section of the POSIX standard at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html specifying that all variable names that modify behavior of the shell or other POSIX-specified utilities shall be all-caps, whereas variable names with at least one lower-case character are reserved for applications to use; read that keeping in mind that environment variables and regular shell variables share a single namespace, so the conventions apply to both).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the if checks for the last run command which is the echo command and therefore it is always 0

to solve this simply move your EXIT_STATUS=$? line directly under the $1 line

Comment: Echo does not matter here, you can remove it. the issue is I want to catch the command which fails no matter of the order. If I remove echo still I will get success as `uptime` is always return 0. your idea is more a hack rather than solution although it fix this example but not resolving if I have lots of command and I want to find the failing cmd.

Comment: then you would need to add a check after every command that updates the var only if its 1

Comment: that's I did and do not like but it seems the only option.

Comment: @MK83, `somecommand || (( exit_status |= $? ))` is your friend, if you want to build up a composite exit status (ORing in each other command's return value into what you eventually return yourself).